# internet access options in remote area? (read: no comcast,qwest, etc)

Tags: internet, 3g

Currently I am living in a fairly "remote" area, in the countryside, and cable internet access through the typical companies like comcast and qwest is just not available here.

I've been trying to research other options for fast internet access. There are some small cable companies but they currently do not offer broadband access here.

I thought about maybe buying a 3g phone with a data plan and doing some sort of tethering, or perhaps getting an android phone and using it as a wireless AP. This would of course depend on 3g being available here.

The only other thing I can think of is some sort of satellite internet service, or doing something crazy like adapting wifi over am radio. Anyone have *any* ideas, at all, short of moving somewhere else?

Comment: Why is this off-topic? It's a question about networking (WAN networking), which seems perfectly on-topic to me.

Comment: That's what I thought....anyway the local cable company finally pulled through with cable internet service. Its 2011 and my family finally gets cable internet. :\

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the three main options are:

- Satellite internet: good bandwidth, but usually needs a separate uplink, needs a dish, usually fairly expensive
- 3G / UMTS: Would work, but if you're remote, chances are you don't have 3G coverage.. worth a test though
- WiFi with a range extender. You can stretch WiFi for a few km with the right hardware... in case a broadband connection is relatively nearby. The same would also work with a microwave or laser transmitter (better range).

You could also try forming a group with neighbours to get broadband together... some communities have done that. Could be a lot of work however.

Answer (score 2):

I think you hit on the two main ones, being Satellite and 3G tethering.

Answer (score 1):

what about [WiMax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiMAX)?